# I need to Concatenate the values and separate with "|" but ignore blanks

Tags: excel, macos

I should start by saying I'm new at this, but I've been asked to get something done at work. I'm using Excel 2008 on a Mac.

I've created a data set that is roughly 3000 rows x 95 columns. the first column is a concatenation of product descriptions, manufacturers, etc. The rows are a list of keywords that I've used the following formula to identify and display in each of the 3000 rows:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(C$3,$A3)),C$2,"") .
```

This has left me with data scattered throughout the sheet. I now need to combine the data from each row into one cell, with each discovered keyword separated by `|`, but I need to ignore blank cells so that I have a result like the following:

```
Keyword1|Keyword3|Keyword4|
```

and not like this:

```
Keyword1||Keyword3|Keyword4||||||||||||
```

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: @ScottCraner Excel 2008 doesn't support VBA. Not sure why the OP has included those tags.

Comment: @Rory that was me, I rolled it back to what the OP had.

Answer (score 0):

You could use & like this:

```
="keyword1"&"|"&"keyword2"&... which does not skip blank cells
```

or if keyword1 is in cell A1 and keyword 2 in B1 then

=IF(OR(A1="",B1=""),"",A1&"|"&B1)

which will leave the result blank if either A1 or B1 are blank

Comment: But this will not skip blank cells.

Comment: there are 95 columns, that approach will become vary hairy

Comment: @ScottCraner very hairy ... perhaps a re-think of the data production would be a better option...

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this years ago when I was trying to create lists of potential racing picks from a list of horses in a race.  I never found something I liked, but used several different methods as I changed my preferences over time.  Here is one somewhat generic solution:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A7&"|"&B7&"|"&...&DM7," ","~"),"|"," "))," ","|"),"~"," ")
```

where the series starting with A7 and ending with DM7 would be replaced with the concatenation you have with multiple "|" symbols.

The formula looks for existing spaces and replaces them with an unused character (in this case, I used a "~"), then it replaces "|" with a " " and uses the TRIM command to eliminate leading and ending spaces as well as excessive spaces in between.  Then it replaces the remaining spaces with "|" and puts back the initial spaces by substituting a space for any "~".

Obviously, this is a bit simpler if your keywords have no spaces, but that was not stated.

Addendum....

Thinking about this last night, I think getting to one concatenated string based on 3000 rows of data with up to 95 columns may be impossible.  This is likely to easily run up against the string limit size of 32,767 since if even 5% of those cells have just a single character, you will have 14,250 characters plus a nearly equal amount of separators.  I do not see how you would do this using the technique I posted.  You could use this technique on a row by row basis and then cut and paste these to a plain text file, but I am beginning to think a native Excel solution would be nearly impossible, especially without VBA which we could have used to write the text out.

Answer (score 0):

While my earlier suggestion might work well for relatively small ranges, it will not work for data approaching the size of the original request.  Excel 2008 on a Mac will not likely be able to handle this, but if you have access to a version of Excel that can use VBA, this suggestion may help you since it uses the extended capabilities of VBA and will put the concatenated data into a text file rather than trying to leave it in the spreadsheet.

I am still trying to figure out a way to do this without using a string or VBA.

I am including some step-by-step information in case it is useful to you or others.

Open the spreadsheet with the 95 rows and 3000 columns of data.
Open the Visual Basic Editor and Choose Insert / Module from the menu.
Paste the following code into the editor window:

```
Option Explicit

Function ConcatNonblankWithSeparator(rngRange As Range, strSeparator As String) As String
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim strReturn As String
    For Each rngCell In rngRange
'        MsgBox rngCell.Address
        If Len(rngCell.Value) > 0 Then
'        MsgBox "before: " & strReturn
            strReturn = strReturn & rngCell.Value & strSeparator
'        MsgBox "after: " & strReturn
        End If
    Next rngCell
'    MsgBox strReturn
'    MsgBox Len(strReturn)
'    MsgBox Len(strSeparator)
    ConcatNonblankWithSeparator = Left(strReturn, Len(strReturn) - Len(strSeparator))
End Function

Sub ConcatRange()
    Dim rngCell As Range
    Dim strSeparator As String
    Dim strFileName As String

    strFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\TestDelimOutput.txt"
    Set rngCell = Sheets("Data").Range("A1:DX3000")
    strSeparator = "|"

    Open strFileName For Output As #1

    Write #1, ConcatNonblankWithSeparator(rngCell, strSeparator)

    Close #1
End Sub
```

The first line protects you (or more likely me) from not defining variables before using them.

The Function creates a fairly generic concatenation routine that takes a range and a string and creates a returned string with nonblank values within the range concatenated and separated by the string.  The msgbox commands can be uncommented (by removing the ' at the start of the line) if you want to see what is going on.  The "MsgBox strReturn" will unlikely display the full amount of the concatenated data due to size limitations of that function, but may during testing.

The Sub actually makes the specific identification of the range to be processed and identifies the separator to be used.  It writes the result to a test file.  If you want a different separator (perhaps a " | " rather than a "|" you would specify it here.  If you want a different sheet name, you would replace "Data" with the name of your sheet (in quotes).  If you have a different range, you would replace the "A1:DX3000" with your range (also in quotes).  If you want to use a different file name, you would specify that in the strFileName variable (along with a path to the location you want to use).

I am a bit of a hacker when it comes to VBA, so someone may suggest some stylistic or technical improvements, but this should get you started.  I did create a 700,000 byte file with this, so it will handle a lot of data.

I hope this points you in a better direction than my earlier post.

Answer (score 0):

What I tried next were some manual steps.  I tried using a Macintosh CSV file but could not work with it because I was having trouble interpreting the end-of-line characters, so I settled for allowing Excel to create an MS-DOS text file in this process.  Your actual process may need to be adapted to your environment.  I used MS Word instead of Notepad or Notepad++ in the hopes that Microsoft has already adapted their search/replace functionality to the MAC.

With the data in a sheet called "Data" in columns A1..DX3000, I created a second sheet with the following formula in A1:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(Data!A1&","&Data!B1&","&Data!C1&","&Data!D1&","&Data!E1&","&Data!F1&","&Data!G1&","&Data!H1&","&Data!I1&","&Data!J1&","&Data!K1&","&Data!L1&","&Data!M1&","&Data!N1&","&Data!O1&","&Data!P1&","&Data!Q1&","&Data!R1&","&Data!S1&","&Data!T1&","&Data!U1&","&Data!V1&","&Data!W1&","&Data!X1&","&Data!Y1&","&Data!Z1&","&Data!AA1&","&Data!AB1&","&Data!AC1&","&Data!AD1&","&Data!AE1&","&Data!AF1&","&Data!AG1&","&Data!AH1&","&Data!AI1&","&Data!AJ1&","&Data!AK1&","&Data!AL1&","&Data!AM1&","&Data!AN1&","&Data!AO1&","&Data!AP1&","&Data!AQ1&","&Data!AR1&","&Data!AS1&","&Data!AT1&","&Data!AU1&","&Data!AV1&","&Data!AW1&","&Data!AX1&","&Data!AY1&","&Data!AZ1&","&Data!BA1&","&Data!BB1&","&Data!BC1&","&Data!BD1&","&Data!BE1&","&Data!BF1&","&Data!BG1&","&Data!BH1&","&Data!BI1&","&Data!BJ1&","&Data!BK1&","&Data!BL1&","&Data!BM1&","&Data!BN1&","&Data!BO1&","&Data!BP1&","&Data!BQ1&","&Data!BR1&","&Data!BS1&","&Data!BT1&","&Data!BU1&","&Data!BV1&","&Data!BW1&","&Data!BX1&","&Data!BY1&","&Data!BZ1&","&Data!CA1&","&Data!CB1&","&Data!CC1&","&Data!CD1&","&Data!CE1&","&Data!CF1&","&Data!CG1&","&Data!CH1&","&Data!CI1&","&Data!CJ1&","&Data!CK1&","&Data!CL1&","&Data!CM1&","&Data!CN1&","&Data!CO1&","&Data!CP1&","&Data!CQ1&","&Data!CR1&","&Data!CS1&","&Data!CT1&","&Data!CU1&","&Data!CV1&","&Data!CW1&","&Data!CX1&","&Data!CY1&","&Data!CZ1&","&Data!DA1&","&Data!DB1&","&Data!DC1&","&Data!DD1&","&Data!DE1&","&Data!DF1&","&Data!DG1&","&Data!DH1&","&Data!DI1&","&Data!DJ1&","&Data!DK1&","&Data!DL1&","&Data!DM1&","&Data!DN1&","&Data!DO1&","&Data!DP1&","&Data!DQ1&","&Data!DR1&","&Data!DS1&","&Data!DT1&","&Data!DU1&","&Data!DV1&","&Data!DW1&","&Data!DX1&","," ","~"),","," "))," ",",")
```

I copied this all the way down to A3000.  This gave me a set of values on each line which were separated by a "|".  Obviously, you would need to adapt this to the actual range you are processing.  By reducing the size to a single line, I did not run into the 32,767 text limit.  Hopefully, you won't either.

I saved this as an MS-DOS text file.

I opened it in MS Word and used its Find/Replace command to replace the paragraph break character (^p) with a "|" and re-saved this as a text file. The resulting file differed from what I wanted to create only by having an extra "|" at the end.

Hopefully, this will work for you or perhaps you need to save it as a Macintosh text file for the Mac version of MS Word to be able to replace the characters at the end of each line.

Not sure if this helps you achieve what you need.  It certainly could work if you only need to do this once or occasionally, but it may be a bit of a pain if this is a frequent task.